# How to access to a state in the render part with for loop?

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, state, render

I have an array in the state and I want to render this array one by one with for loop.
I can't figure out how to get the length of array, any idea?
Thank you for the help.
here is my code:

```
this.state = {
    array: []
}
// here is the function to write data into array
render(){
   return(
         <div>
            for(let i = 0; i < this.state.array.length; i++) { //this line doesn't work, error with length part
               <p> {this.state.array[i]}</p> // this line will work if I wirte outside of loop
            }
          </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for-loop constructs don't work in JSX like they do in javascript, since you aren't returning anything in the loop.

Just use `array.prototype.map` to map `state.array` to the JSX you want to render for each element within the array. By mapping the state you needn't worry about the array length, the `map` function handles it.

```
this.state = {
    array: []
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.array.map((el, i) => (<p key={i}>{el}</p>))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) - Official docs for rendering lists of data

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I am new for the JS. Thank you for writing the working code.

Comment: @LiLian Welcome. I also linked the react docs on rendering arrays, I highly recommend you read through as much of the React docs as you can. They are incredibly well written and maintained. Welcome to React, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
render(){
   return(
         <div>
         {
              this.state.array.map((element, index) => {
                  return (
                        <p key={`key-${index}`}>{element}</p>
                  );
              })
         }
          </div>
    )
}
```

Don't forget the key prop when rendering multiple components in a loop in React.